# Has JsRuntime.InvokeAsync a return value size limitation?

Tags: blazor, blazor-jsinterop

When I try to call a JavaScript function from a Blazor function the connection between my serverside Blazor App and the server breaks, when the function returns a string which is longer than 32,721 charakters. I'

In my Razor page I execute:

```
var data = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("myfunction");
```

The JavaScript function `myfunction` looks like this:

```
function myfunction() {
  return 'x'.repeat(32721);
}
```

This works, but when I use `32722` as argument the connection breaks and I don't know why and how to work around this.

Splitting the string in 1000 byte long chungs and returning a string[] didn't work as well.

I need to return around 200.000 bytes. Is there any limitation?

Watching the messages of the websocket I can see the message with 103kB, then "JS.RenderBatch", "OnRenderCompleted" and finally "Connection closed with an error" but I can not find any error message in any console or log.

Comment: It's the SignalR message size limit. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17084). There's also [this from the MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/advanced-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1#perform-large-data-transfers-in-blazor-server-apps) on chunking a response to work around the message size limitation.

Comment: I'd like to accept this as answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the SignalR message size limit. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17084). There's also [this from the MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/advanced-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1#perform-large-data-transfers-in-blazor-server-apps) on chunking a response to work around the message size limitation.